# How to get string value in Android?

Tags: android, string

Currently i am working in Android, I have one string like result below mentioned here for your reference, but i didn't get this, please help me

```
String result ="error: not allowed | Native: XYZ ABC - Vodofone | Amount balance: 434"
```

How to get that Native value like "XYZ ABC - Vodofone"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not your personal code writing agency. Looking at your previous question you've basically already been provided with a lot of code that parses strings.

Answer (score 3):

Use `split` method of the `String` class:

```
String result ="error: not allowed | Native: XYZ ABC - Vodofone | Amount balance: 434"
String[] results = result.split("|");
// results[0] = "error: not allowed "
// results[1] = "Native: XYZ ABC - Vodofone "
// results[2] = "Amount balance: 434 "
```

The resulting entries as shown in the comments are now, placed in the `String` array.

Comment: I tried this String[] Answer =result.split("|");
                     System.out.println("Result : "+Answer[1]);

Comment: Don't understand you - "*Answer comes in E*"? What E? BTW I am not your coder for your question! You have to work out the rest of it for *yourself*

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

`result.substring(result.indexOf('|'), result.lastIndexOf('|'));`

or `result.split("|");`